# How to make Angular Material Table with sticky first column

Tags: css, angular, angular-material-5

Is there any way to make Angular Material with a sticky first column using CSS?.

Here is ready to edit [Stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnyxbz)

I have tried to adapt this solution https://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/BmLpV/ but for some reasons, the first column is thrown out of the table itself and it loses styling.

```
<div class="zui-wrapper">
    <div class="zui-scroller">
        <table class="zui-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col">Name</th>..........
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">DeMarcus Cousins</td>
.......
                <tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


.zui-scroller {
    margin-left: 141px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the angular material version 6 this has been made easy.

You can add `sticky` tag on columns that need to be sticky on the left of the table and `stickyEnd` tag for the ones on the right of the table.

here is a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kooxxyvddeqb?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.ts)

Answer (score 2):

```
td:first-child, th:first-child {
  position:sticky;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used stickyEnd to achieve this like below.

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="12" class="white-bg" stickyEnd>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mat-table-sticky:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<ng-container
            matColumnDef="name"
            sticky
>
</ng-container>
```

---

> `

```css
.mat-table-sticky:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

`

---

Comment: There is no explanation as to why this answers the question.  Could you add some clarity please?  In addition, please read our [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

in template.html to table (#table)

```
<table mat-table #table>
```

====Component.ts

```
 @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<any>;

 ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
   if (this.table) {
     this.table.updateStickyColumnStyles();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me  using;

`    :host ::ng-deep .mat-cell:first-child, .mat-header-cell:first-child {

position: sticky;

position: -webkit-sticky;

right:0;

z-index:1;

background:inherit;

border-left: 1px solid grey;

}    `